# PHP + Smarty database results

Tags: php, database, smarty, prestashop

I need to get some info from my database and display it in .tpl (smarty file). My sample code:
PHP code:

```
global $smarty;
$db = Db::getInstance();
$this->_sql = 'SELECT `clientName`, `clientWebsite`, `clientFeedBack` FROM `ps_feedBackPresta` WHERE `confirm`="1" AND `approve`="1"';
$config = $db->getRow($this->_sql);
$smarty->assign('feedBacks', $config);
```

And my smarty code:

```
<a href="{$feedBacks.clientWebsite}" title="{$feedBacks.clientName}">{$feedBacks.clientName}</a><br />
        {$feedBacks.clientFeedBack}
```

Output result:
[image: Img 1]

With this code everything works fine (include with cyrillic) but when I try to output more results wiht {foreach} and this code in my .tpl:

```
{foreach $feedBacks as $feedBackss}
        <a href="{$feedBackss.clientWebsite}" title="{$feedBackss.clientName}">{$feedBackss.clientName}</a><br />
        {$feedBackss.clientFeedBack}
        {/foreach}
```

The result is:
[image: Img 2]

So where is my false and how to fix it? It's my second day of headbanging :)

BR,
George :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Print_r($config)
```

Will show you what your data looks like before it goes to smarty

Comment: Yes, I know about that but my false is in the database getting method :)

Comment: `{$feedBackss.clientFeedBack}` is not what you think it is, print out the array and see what it actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem lies with `$config = $db->getRow($this->_sql);`. You're selecting a single row, not an array of them. get all the rows and your foreach will work. When in doubt, test with `$config = array($db->getRow($this->_sql));`

Comment: $db->getRow($this->_sql) shows only first row (I don't know that) and with array($db->getRow($this->_sql)) the only change is the type of array from one-dimensional to two-dimensional... I must use $db->ExecuteS($this->_sql);